# SQL Server time sheet calculation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2012

I have a time punch program the outputs the data set below. `RECTYP_43` are the (1) in and (2) out punches. I need a query to look at the look at the `LOGINDATE_43` and `LOGINTIME_43` and the `RECTYPE_43` and get the difference between 1 and 2.

I thought this would be easier than it has proven to be.

```
empid_43    RECTYPE_43  LOGINDATE_43            LOGINTIME_43
------------------------------------------------------------
127            1        2016-10-21 00:00:00.000     0558
127            2        2016-10-21 00:00:00.000     1430
127            2        2016-10-21 00:00:00.000     1201
127            1        2016-10-21 00:00:00.000     1228
127            1        2016-10-24 00:00:00.000     0557
127            2        2016-10-24 00:00:00.000     1200
127            1        2016-10-24 00:00:00.000     1228
127            2        2016-10-24 00:00:00.000     1430
2589           2        2016-10-21 00:00:00.000     1431
2589           1        2016-10-21 00:00:00.000     0556
2589           1        2016-10-24 00:00:00.000     0550
2589           2        2016-10-24 00:00:00.000     1431
2589           2        2016-10-24 00:00:00.000     1201
2589           1        2016-10-24 00:00:00.000     1226
69             1        2016-10-24 00:00:00.000     1229
69             2        2016-10-24 00:00:00.000     1430
69             1        2016-10-24 00:00:00.000     0555
69             2        2016-10-24 00:00:00.000     1200
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a CTE to get all the punch-ins and then a subquery to find the first punch out that comes after that time...

```
;WITH ctePunchIn AS (
    SELECT empid_43, LOGINDATE_43 AS Date_In, LOGINTIME_43 AS Time_In 
    FROM #Table1 
    WHERE [RECTYPE_43] = 1
 )

 SELECT 
    empid_43, Date_In, Time_In 
    ,(SELECT TOP 1 LOGINTIME_43 FROM #Table1 WHERE 
        (empid_43 = ctePunchIn.empid_43) 
        AND 
        (LOGINDATE_43 = ctePunchIn.Date_In)
        AND 
        (LOGINTIME_43 > ctePunchIn.Time_In) 
        AND 
        (RECTYPE_43 = 2) 
        ORDER BY empid_43, Date_In, LOGINTIME_43) AS Time_Out
FROM 
    ctePunchIn
```

Answer (score 0):

Dazedandconfused's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40243877/2505574) works if the logout Time is the same date as the login time, but if the user logs out on a different day to logging in, it will not work.

e.g.

```
INSERT into Punch (empId_43, RecType_43, LoginDate_43, LoginTime_43)
VALUES (15, 1, '2016-01-01', '2305'),
(15, 2, '2016-01-02', '0005');
```

In order to accomodate for this, you need to know what the next item in the table is for that employee. And with that, you can ensure that the next item is also a logout event. This will help capture situations where someone has forgotten to punch out.

Extending the CTE can provide a more complete solution:

```
WITH Data AS
(
    SELECT  empId_43,
            RecType_43,
            LoginDate_43,
            LoginTime_43,
            RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY empId_43 
                                  ORDER BY LoginDate_43, LoginTime_43)
    FROM Punch
)
SELECT  PIn.empId_43 [Employee],
        PIn.LoginDate_43 [LoginDate],
        PIn.LoginTime_43 [LoginTime],
        POut.LoginDate_43 [LogoutDate],
        POut.LoginTime_43 [LogoutTime]
FROM Data PIn
    LEFT JOIN Data POut ON PIn.empId_43 = POut.empId_43
        AND POut.RecType_43 = 2
        AND POut.RowNum = PIn.RowNum + 1
WHERE PIn.RecType_43 = 1
ORDER BY PIn.empId_43, PIn.LoginDate_43, PIn.LoginTime_43;
```

However, `Row_Number` *can* be inefficient. Doing this is best when looking at a small subset (e.g. a particular date range, etc).

Answer (score 0):

slightly different way of doing it:

```
select
   punchIn.empid_43,
   punchIn.login as dateTime_in,
   punchout.login as dateTime_out
from
(
    SELECT  empId_43,
            RecType_43,
            LoginDate_43,
            LoginTime_43,
            dateadd('n',right(logintime_43,2),
            dateadd('hh',left(LoginTime_43,2), 
            LoginDate_43)) as login,
            RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY empId_43 
                                  ORDER BY LoginDate_43, LoginTime_43)
    FROM Punch
where rectype_43 = 1
) punchIn left outer join 
(
    SELECT  empId_43,
            RecType_43,
            LoginDate_43,
            LoginTime_43,
            dateadd('n',right(logintime_43,2),
            dateadd('hh',left(LoginTime_43,2), 
            LoginDate_43)) as login,
            RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY empId_43 
                                  ORDER BY LoginDate_43, LoginTime_43)
    FROM Punch
where rectype_43 = 2
) punchOut on
punchin.empID = punchout.empID and
punchin.rownum = punchout.rownum
```

assuming all punchin rows have a corresponding punchout row